# Heroku Pushing My Rails app as Play

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, playframework

I have a rails app called MBAToolbox. When I enter the directory and type "play", I get the following:

This is not a play application!

That's good! Now I type rails c and I am entered into the rails command line. Clearly this is a rails app. But when I type 'heroku create' and push 'git push heroku master', heroku tries to deploy this as a 'play' app?

I saw on their site that Heroku states:

> Heroku Play framework support will be applied to applications that
>   match:
>       */conf/application.conf in any directory except for the modules directory
>       , when determining to use Play.

I don't have that. My directory is as follows:

```
drwxr-xr-x  21 admin  staff   714 Mar 22 00:20 .
drwxr-xr-x  26 admin  staff   884 Mar 21 21:39 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 admin  staff  6148 Mar 21 23:37 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff   430 Mar 21 21:39 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  12 admin  staff   408 Mar 22 00:22 .idea
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff   935 Mar 21 22:38 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff  3884 Mar 21 22:38 Gemfile.lock
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff  9208 Mar 21 21:39 README.rdoc
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff   275 Mar 21 21:39 Rakefile
drwxr-xr-x   9 admin  staff   306 Mar 21 21:57 app
drwxr-xr-x  10 admin  staff   340 Mar 21 21:56 config
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff   160 Mar 21 21:39 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x   6 admin  staff   204 Mar 22 00:06 db
drwxr-xr-x   3 admin  staff   102 Mar 21 21:39 doc
drwxr-xr-x   5 admin  staff   170 Mar 21 21:48 lib
drwxr-xr-x   4 admin  staff   136 Mar 21 21:39 log
drwxr-xr-x   9 admin  staff   306 Mar 21 23:37 public
drwxr-xr-x   3 admin  staff   102 Mar 21 21:39 script
drwxr-xr-x   8 admin  staff   272 Mar 21 21:39 test
drwxr-xr-x   6 admin  staff   204 Mar 21 21:53 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   4 admin  staff   136 Mar 21 21:39 vendor
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) article on the Heroku dev site covers both ends of this. It has a pointer to the actual source of the Play buildpack, so you can read the code that figures out which buildpack to use. You can also explicitly pick the Rails buildpack instead.